# How do I choose to avoid brown stringy fibres in avocado?

Tags: fruit, salad-dressing, avocados

How do I choose to avoid brown stringy fibres in avocado?

The brown stringy fibres in avocado taste not good and looks not good when there are brown stringy fibres, especially making avocado dressings or serve in slices.

Comment: Are your avocados a little over ripe?

Comment: mayb not, they are still quite firm...thats why i am wondering if the appearance of the fibres are related to avocado qualities, as I usually bought a pack of them.

Comment: I really can't say what is happening, but if possible can you buy them individually to try to control things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The brown stringy fibers form in the avocado flesh after it is bruised or the avocado is past ripe.

The way to avoid this is to plan ahead. Buy your avocados when they are green and very hard. Try to select ones that have not been abused (at least if you *see* one being knocked around, take a different one). When you get the avocados home, set them aside in a safe place for a couple/few days, & don't drop or manhandle them in the meantime. When they are ripe (yield slightly to gentle pressure, as they say) you have a couple days to use them. Putting them in the refrigerator can prolong their niceness a little bit if you are not quite ready to use them. Unless some mishap befell them before purchase, they should be beautiful and without those horrible stringy lesions.